# Eclipse stuck at plugin installation (marketplace)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using an Eclipse IDE for Java Developers version 2019-12 (4.14.0). As there were no JSP support, I went to [Eclipse site](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-xml-editors-and-tools-0#group-details) and drag and drop the **install** button to my eclipse. It started the installation but even after hours it stuck around 80%.

I restarted the Eclipse and even my machine but as an when I click on the Marketplace, the dialog shown in the image comes up and stuck there. The cancel button also doesn't work.

Please help..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JSPs, you actually want https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-enterprise-java-developer-tools, but if you keep running into this issue, it sounds more like a problem with your network.

To rule out any issue with it being on the client, you can add https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest into your **Available Software Sites** preference page, **Check for Updates** from the **Help** menu, and then try the directions at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F. If everything else fails, the downloadable package at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-12/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers is an option (for the next week, after which 2021-03 will have been Released).

Comment: Hi The last link downloadable package is what? It is a eclipse installer?

Comment: A compressed and already assembled copy to just unzip and run.

Comment: SO, I will have to wait one week in order to download it... right?

Comment: No, it's a link to 2020-12, which is available now. 2021-03, the next release, comes out Wednesday.